# Swift: Want to add value to NSTableView(1st ViewController) from secondViewController

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview

so I have been able to use delegates and protocols to pass data from secondViewController to the firstViewController. Till now I have been showing data as a label in the 1stVC. Now I want to add it to NSTableView.

I am finding it a bit hard to get the hang of TableView. Basically I am using the variable (data) that stores the values/string inserted in the secondViewController. I imagine, I use the data variable to show it on TableView?

I want the delete button to be on the firstViewController, so essentially you can delete the value from the firstViewController but can only insert it from the secondVC.

Anyone here who can help me with the code both for tableView & adding data to the row!

Comment: `NSTableView` has nothing to do with iOS. Please decide whether you want help on iOS or macOS

Comment: my bad, I accidentally selected iOS from tags rather than osx. Got it fixed now!